# Eclipse Will Not Recognize Galaxy S 2 When Debugging Even Though It Will Recognise My Touch

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a java beginner. I am going through a book right now actually called Java in 24 Hours sixth edition by Rogers Cadenhead learning java and android programming. Anyways, to my problem. I am using eclipse to make a simple app and I want to transfer it to my galaxy s 2. I am ready to debug it and pick my device.... except its not there. I have installed Kies, the drivers, made sure its in USB debug mode but it will not recognize it. Any suggestions? This is not a duplicate! It is different because even though its in debugging mode, even though Ive reinstalled kies twice, even though Ive made sure the USB port or cord is not a problem it still does not work! But whats strange is my My Touch will work perfectly with the app. What am I missing here? HELP PLEASE.

Comment: Operating System? Ubuntu?

Comment: Oh. Windows XP 64 bit.

Comment: Does it say unrecognized device or just doesn't do anything?

Comment: And its Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Comment: when I go to pick my devices from the android device chooser, its just simply not there.

Answer (score -1):

You are most likely having a problem with the adb in your platform-tools folder. It is the android device bridge. Go to the android-sdk folder and then go to platform-tools and inside you  will see adb. Press shift + right click anywhere in an empty spot of that folder and click on 'open a command line here.' Type: `adb devices`. It should show you a list of usable devices. If that doesn't show your galaxy (it will be a big number/letter sequence like: 3ANIWRN42408) or anything than try `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`. And then see if `adb devices` shows your device.

If that is hard to follow, check this out: [adb/usb tutorial](http://theunlockr.com/2009/10/06/how-to-set-up-adb-usb-drivers-for-android-devices/)

Comment: err. Sorry but I have to ask where the sdk folder is. I know where the sdk manager is but no the folder. Really early beginner.

Comment: Not a problem. It just depends on where you downloaded it. I would just do a search for android in C:\ and look for the main folder and keep track of it.

Comment: Inside that folder you will see folders like: tools, platform-tools, samples,  etc..

Comment: I did the first thing you said to do. When i opened it, it opened a window with code that scrolled down really fast and closed before I even knew what happened. it does this every time I open it.

Comment: Any other help from anyone would be great!